# Get offset minutes from IANA (TZDB) time zone

Tags: c#, linq, timezone

I have a table `T1` with `Id`, `Name` and `TimeZone` as columns. The `TimeZone` column has IANA (TZDB) format like `America/Chicago`
I'm getting the data from `T1` like

```
response = T1.Where(t => t.Id == 9).Select(rez => new
           {
              RezName = rez .Name,
              Offset = ...
           });
```

Inside `Offset` I need to get the current offset in minutes (like -300 for `America/Chicago` that has offset -05).
Is there a way to get the offset minutes inside the LINQ query or only by iterating after the select and calculate the local time for each element?

Comment: One can't get "the offset" from a time zone.  It's a one-to-many relationship, not one-to-one. Do you want the *current* offset? Or do you want the offset that applies at some other point in time? Or do you want the offset that is currently considered the "Standard Time" offset?  Please clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, you tagged your question with `nodatime`.  Are you specifically looking for an answer that leverages Noda Time? Depending on the version and OS of .NET you are targeting, you may not necessarily need it to achieve that particular goal.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint The current offset. Edited my question

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Not specifically. Many of my IANA time zone searches leaded me to nodatime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you originally tagged your question with `nodatime`, here is how you can leverage NodaTime for this:

```
using NodaTime;
```

...

```
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant();
response = T1.Where(t => t.Id == 9)
   .Select(rez => new
   {
      RezName = rez.Name,
      TimeZone = rez.TimeZone
   })
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(x => new
   {
      RezName = x.RezName,
      Offset = (int) DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[x.TimeZone]
                         .GetUtcOffset(now).ToTimeSpan().TotalMinutes
   });
```

If you are leveraging .NET on Linux or macOS, or if you are using .NET 6 or higher on Windows, you can do this without Noda Time:

```
DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant();
response = T1.Where(t => t.Id == 9)
   .Select(rez => new
   {
      RezName = rez.Name,
      TimeZone = rez.TimeZone
   })
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(x => new
   {
      RezName = x.RezName,
      Offset = (int) TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(x.TimeZone)
                         .GetUtcOffset(now).TotalMinutes
   });
```

Yet another alternative would be to use `TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo from [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter) with similar code to the second example.

Keep in mind, that all of these return the *current* offset from UTC (as minutes, with positive values being East of GMT).  For `America/Chicago`, that's presently `-300` because daylight saving time is in effect.  When daylight time ends, it will return `-360`.

Note that in the above examples, the time zone code must occur after the query materializes, as it would be impossible for a LINQ provider like EF to translate it to a SQL query.

Comment: (not sure why you have `t.Id == 9` hardcoded either - but I just carried it over from your example.

Comment: I'm receiving that value as a parameter. I've used 9, as an example :)

Comment: Why .NET 6 or higher? I don't see anything in the second code snippet that would require such a high version?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint If I'm adding ToList() to the query I'm getting "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan ToTimeSpan()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression" for both approaches

Comment: @Sweeper - .NET 6 added built-in conversion from Windows to IANA time zone identifiers.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#time-zone-conversion-apis

Comment: @Dana - You'll need to do the time zone conversion after materializing the query.  I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Oh right. Actually, I misread the “or” before “if you are using.NET 6” as an “and”, and was wondering why .NET 6 was still needed if the OS is already Linux/macOS, which uses the IANA database. Haha :)